# Unable to open NetCDF version 4 files in R

Tags: r, version, netcdf

It seems that the current version of the ncdf package is not able to open NetCDF Version 4 files. See: [Error when trying to import NetCDF to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443211/error-when-trying-to-import-netcdf-to-r)

In the resolution to that question, Johannes explained that he managed to run the ncdf4 package on a Windows machine and open the file that way.

However, when I try to run the ncdf4 package, I receive the error: "Error: package ‘ncdf4’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it". Does anyone know how to run this package on a Windows machine? (In the previous thread, Johannes said "package installation was a little bit complicated under win 64bit".)

Other ideas on how to load this file would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, one way to get around the installation issue can be found here in the ncdf documentation:
http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncdf/

Download the zip file from the following link

MS Windows (32-bit R version 3.0.1): http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncdf/win32/ncdf4_1.9.zip

MS Windows (64-bit R version 3.1.0): http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncdf/win64/ncdf4_1.12.zip

Installation for windows:

Use the R graphical user interface and pick the menu item to "install a package from a local file". Then select the ncdf4_1.9.zip file"

Hope this helps!